# What is the purpose of curly braces without logic statements proceeding them?

Tags: php

I had a piece of code not working as I intended.

The code was roughly like this:

```
foreach ($arrayOfIds as $iterId)
{
    if ($iterId === $unchangingId)
    {
        // ...
    }

}
```

The problem was that it was going into the if statement regardless of whether the IDs matched or not.

Then I noticed that my if statement was incorrectly declared, and actually looked like this:

```
if ($iterId === $unchangingId);
{
    // ...
}
```

That single semi colon gave me *so much* grief.

Now, I know how/why I didn't get a compiler or runtime error because of the 
    if ($iterId === $unchangingId);

but I never knew you could have code inside 2 curly braces like that, without anything else.

I want to learn more about this, and what it gets used for, if anyone could elaborate on it I'd be extremely grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($iterId === $unchangingId);
{
    // ...
}
```

This is two separate and unrelated constructs.

An [`if`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) construct can take the form of:

```
if (expression) statement;
```

without curly braces when used with a single statement, and that statement doesn't have to have anything in it but the terminating semicolon. So

```
if ($iterId === $unchangingId);
```

is a complete, standalone thing which you're then following with the unrelated statement block wrapped in braces:

```
{
    // ...
}
```

which does nothing special, the contents are handled just as if the curly braces weren't there.

Answer (score 1):

In Java a naked curly braced block has local scope. In PHP, it doesn't do anything.